# Process multiple files, pull out multiple matches and print (save) to a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I’m trying to parse multiple files to create a summary report. Each file contains multiple lines of interest which I want to combine into a single line. Each file contains the following data set that I am matching on:

```
connect *changing value*
*changing value* #0x *changing value* 
*changing value* #0x *changing value*
*changing value* #0x *changing value*
*changing value* #0x *changing value*
```

My crude command line is as follows

```
cat * | grep -E "#0x|connect" | awk '/connect/{CON=$0;next } /#0x/{ print CON "," $0}'
```

but this only combines four matches for each file in the format which leads to

```
connect <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value>
connect <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value>
connect <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value>
connect <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value>
```

when I want the following (four lines into one) for each file

```
connect <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value> , <changing value> #0x <changing value>
```

Comment: can you extend your input for at least 2-3 files?

Comment: Do you guarantee that each file will have exactly one `connect`  line and four ``#0x`` lines (in that order)?  If not, is there any data pattern that always appears after the last ``#0x`` line (but not before)?

Comment: The output from the grep will be in that format, connect and four #0X then the next file and so on